# Mysterious msChart in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I want to zoom **chart** when I **scroll** the **wheel** in **Chart.Axes**. But in some times scroll don't work. 
Ex: [image]

*position 1 :* I scroll the wheel and my chart zooms
But! 
*position 2 :* I scroll the whell , byt the chart doesn't zooms!

Why? What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

when we create msChart (XAML) - In LinearAxis  we mast set property Background  to Transparent